# from pdo to array to table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to get a array into a Table. Now i have this result :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [rsname] => Fake Suomi [overallxpnow] =>
>   5000000000 ) [1] => Array ( [rsname] => Alkan [overallxpnow] =>
>   3213351169 ) [2] => Array ( [rsname] => Zezima [overallxpnow] =>
>   1741311015 ) [3] => Array ( [rsname] => Joaaaa [overallxpnow] =>
>   1215344088 ) [4] => Array ( [rsname] => 30 [overallxpnow] => 561923956
>   ) )

This is my code:

```
<?php print_r($top5p);      ?>
```

Now i have no idea how to get this into a table, i did some research but i didn't get any better out of that.

Comment: use foreach and insert it using mysql insert query

Comment: you want to insert it in database table or to show it in html table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($arr as $itm): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $itm['rsname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $itm['overallxpnow']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Ofc you can write it in different ways, this is the one I preffer.

Comment: thank you! it is working just how i wanted it to work!